# Transfer a directory over ssh with sudo

Tags: command-line, ssh, sudo, tar, gzip

I am trying to transfer a directory from a remote server(CentOS) to my local machine(Ubuntu) over ssh. There are two users : A and B. User A can ssh into remote server and has sudo access. User B owns a directory in remote server.

To transfer a directory owned by User B as User A, sudo needs to be used.

Currently for transferring a file (from remote to local) this is what I am using :

```
ssh -tt userA@remote_host 'stty raw -echo; sudo cat /path/to/remote/file/owned/by/userB' > /path/to/local/file
```

To transfer a directory I have tried the tar approach,

```
ssh -tt userA@remote_host 'stty raw -echo; sudo tar -C /path/to/remote/directory/owned/by/userB/ -czf - .' | tar -C /path/lo/local/directory -xzf -
```

However on the local system I get this error :

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you running ssh with a TTY? Can you make the command work without using a TTY (and without running stty)?

Comment: @Kenster If I run without the `-t` option, I get this error : `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

Comment: [`ssh` with separate stdin, stdout, stderr AND tty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/653431/108618).

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to transfer directory using ssh

```
ssh -tt userA@remote_host 'stty raw -echo; sudo tar -C /path/to/remote/directory/owned/by/userB/ -czf - .' | tar -C /path/lo/local/directory -xzf -
```

Piping the above command's output to cat (in local system) instead of tar, gives more info :

```
$ ssh -tt userA@remote_host 'stty raw -echo; sudo tar -C /path/to/remote/directory/owned/by/userB/ -czf - .' | cat
userA@remote_host's password: 
gzip: compressed data not written to a terminal. Use -f to force compression.
For help, type: gzip -h
Connection to remote_host closed.
```

To fix this, I used this command :

```
ssh -t userA@remote_host 'stty raw -echo; sudo tar -C /path/to/remote/directory/owned/by/userB/ -cf - . | gzip -9nf' | tar -C  /path/lo/local/directory -xzf -
```

**Note for ssh options**

Since I am using `sudo` to access User B's directory, `ssh` returns `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo` if `-t` option is not used.

`-t` : Force pseudo-terminal allocation

**Note for stty options**

The `stty` option `-echo` is optional. It is to be used (I think) if `sudo` requires you to enter password.

`raw` : Process input as it is (do not interpret special characters, etc.)

`-echo` : Do not print typed characters

**Note for gzip options**

`-9` :  Set compression to maximum

`-f` :  Force compression (*As suggested by the error*)

`-n`, `--no-name` : Does not include name and timestamp of the file (Helpful to compare checksums of the file in remote and local)

Comment: Note this is still fragile. If `tar` or `gzip` encounters a minor problem that would otherwise not break the operation entirely, a warning printed to stderr will contaminate the stream your local `tar` gets. There are scenarios when your tty prints something beyond your control (somebody uses `wall` or schedules a shutdown with `shutdown`, which generates a broadcast message); see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12450/108618).

Comment: I agree, but my options are limited apart from moving the file owned by User B to a directory owned by me(User A) and then `scp` it to local. File integrity check using checksums is the only option in the event of the scenarios you mention.

Comment: `File integrity check using checksums is the only option` – Not quite. An additional channel is possible, e.g. by sending a stream via a forwarded port. Someone rogue can write to the same port though. Forwarding a Unix socket, when done properly, can solve this. But using sockets requires more knowledge, tools and effort. Are you interested?